# How increase the logo size in website odoo 13?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, odoo

I tried to increase the logo size on the website home page in `Odoo 13` but the code of show logo is different in `Odoo 13` version, how to increase the logo in this code? it tries to put

```
<"style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"/>
```

in span but not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<data inherit_id="website.layout" name="Show Logo">

    <xpath expr="//header//a[hasclass('navbar-brand')]" position="replace">

        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand logo">

            <span t-field="website.logo" t-options="{'widget': 'image'}" role="img" t-att-aria-label="'Logo of %s' % website.name"  t-att-title="website.name" />

        </a>

    </xpath>

</data>
```